# Jquery Mask não está funcionando no In App Browser do Ionic

Tags: ionic, inappbrowser

Tenho um input type  que carrega uma mascara Jquery.

```
$(element).inputmask('99/9999');
```

Pelo Browser funciona perfeitamente, porém quando navego pelo App (do `IONIC` que utiliza o "InApp Browser"), em alguns celulares não deixa digitar nada.

Alguém tem alguma para ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver este problema retirando o `MaxLength` do `Input`.